# angular js routing with parameters

Tags: angularjs

In the below mentioned angular code I am trying to use Angular js routing feature.

Below is the partial code related to routing

```
...........
...
TicketApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider 

     // EXPECTING THIS ROUTE TO BE EXECUTED 
      .when('/EditTicket/:idx', {
        templateUrl: '../Ticket/EditTicket/',            
        controller: 'EditTicketCtrl'
    })

.otherwise({
    templateUrl: '../Account/AllUsers',
    controller: 'AllUsersCtrl'
});
.......
....
```

When user clicks a hyper link below function gets called

```
 $scope.Edit = function (idx) {

     $location.path('/EditTicket'/idx);     

};
```

When the above function gets executed instead of  .when('/EditTicket/:idx'.. , the 
otherwise part is getting executed.
Please let me know what needs to be changed so that the .when('/EditTicket/:idx' gets executed.

Comment: you are not passing the param properly, it should be `$location.path('/EditTicket/' + idx);`

Comment: @Arun James, Yes, your observation was correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should write -

```
$scope.Edit = function (idx) {
     $location.path('/EditTicket/' + idx);     
};
```

Comment: can you tell how to access the idx paramter in templateUrl